# Spring not overriding active profile from command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

Here is my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  freemarker:
    template-loader-path: classpath:/templates

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp
    username: postgres
    password: password
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: false
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop


---

spring:
  profiles:
    active: development


---

spring:
  profiles: staging

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

logging:
  level:
    root: DEBUG

---

spring:
  profiles: production

  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

I run the application using:

```
java -jar application.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=staging
```

In the log, I can see that spring boot prints out:
**The following profiles are active: development**

So why isn't the active profile set to *staging* even though I explicitly set it in the command line args?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The order matters. To set a system property, use

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=staging application.jar
```

The line you mentioned passes an application argument.

Answer (score 5):

**Launches a Java application.** By command

```
java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]
```

**Spring Profiles**  [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles)

> The Spring Environment has an API for this, but you would normally set a System property (spring.profiles.active) or an OS environment variable (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE). Also, you can launch your application with a -D argument (remember to put it before the main class or jar archive), as follows:

```
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

> In Spring Boot, you can also set the active profile in application.properties, as shown in the following example:

```
spring.profiles.active=production
```

> You can use a spring.profiles.active Environment property to specify which profiles are active, You could also specify it on the command line by using the following switch: [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles)

```
$ java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

> For multiple profiles

```
$ java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb
```

Comment: " --spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb " how actually this works? if I run in a same server does it really matter?? which properties it will take at the end?

Comment: From the document https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles`The spring.profiles.active property follows the same ordering rules as other properties: The highest PropertySource wins` and for me it seems `hsqldb` takes highest priority @Sam

Answer (score 3):

you have to specify options before your jar file and arguments after it

```
java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
```

-Dspring.profiles.active=staging is an option and not argument. so please change it to the following

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=staging application.jar
```